# Pass WPF textbox.text from Window1 to data class

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, class

I have a WPF window that collects data and sends it to a data class where it is saved to a xml file. I want to name this file in a textbox on the Window1 form and then pass it to the data class so the file can be saved. I know I have to let the data class know that the Window1 exists, but I'm having trouble with the syntax - I guess.

Comment: Type MVVM into a search engine of your choice. This concept describes how to arrange classes so that they can be used in WPF efficiently.

Comment: Matthias, I am attempting to learn MVVM which is what brought to the question I posted above. I like the efficency and manageability, but something isn't clicking. Nevertheless, thanks for your input. I will continue my search for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it the other way around: Your *view* (WPF) should know a *view model* (wrapper) which knows how to collect the data, that should be used to save the file. This VM should know the *model* (the implementation of your file save stuff among other models like data sources etc.) and feed it with the necessary information.

Using this approach combined with nootification, you can always swap out several parts without affecting the others.

- The *model* (back end) is completely independant of anything else.
- The *view* can be defined elsewhere and shouldn't use any code behind (except for the definition of the VM and some events). It only binds to the VM.
- The *view model* puts everything together. It provides the data structure, that can be used and presented in WPF. Through binding the VM informs WPF of updates etc.

In your case:

- Design a nice GUI
- Design a VM that can collect all necessary information.
- Write a method that takes all parameters required for your file.
- In an event or command handler (click etc.) call the VM method that passes all collected info to the file method.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM can handle all this for you.
You could take a look at the following website which explains the MVVM pattern with a (downloadable) code-example: [MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

It might be a bit hard to get into if you're new to MVVM. I found the following links (and website in general) to be pretty usefull to grasp the concept: [Christian Mosers MVVM Pattern](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html).

Also take a look at this to set up your commands:
[Christian Mosers DelegateCommand](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

Good luck !